# Facebook graph api - How to get the count of tagged photos

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get the count of tagged photos for a user.

When getting the user albums using "me/albums" there is a 'count' field for every album containing the photos count in each album. When using "me/photos" to get all tagged photos, there is no 'count' field.

Is there any other query that can supply this kind of data? 
Went over the graph api documentation and found nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's a count field for tagged photos, and there is no `COUNT` operator in FQL, so the most efficient way is to minimize the return packet and count them yourself:

```
fql?q=SELECT '' FROM photo_tag WHERE subject=me()
```