# FQL - Count tagged photos with each friend

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql

I need to count the number of tagged photos you share with your friends from 2 years back.

Currently I am calling the graph with

```
/me/photos?fields=id,tags,created_time&limit=2000&since=1284374555
```

This retrieves all my photos from the last two years...
I then loop through all my photo tags, and use a counter to count the number of tags for each friend.

This is pretty slow...

I was wondering if it's possible to use a single FQL query to do this, and return a single array of all your friends, with these three attributes for each friend:

```
    name = Joe Bloggs //Friend name
    id = 7643785634 //Friend id
    tag_count = 45 //Tags you share with each other
```

I know this will be a fairly complex query. So any help is much appreciated.

Comment: FQL does not have a `count` method, so you'll still have to count friends tags individually. Unlike the API, you'll need to use a multiquery to get all this data and then loop through multiple objects to assemble it back together. If I were developing with JS, I'd use your API query rather than FQL for this.

Comment: Would this be useful? http://stackoverflow.com/a/8540284/698289